How can I host a Python Web API built with Flask on IIS?
I have developed a Python-based Web API using frameworks such as Flask or FastAPI and need to deploy it on an IIS (Internet Information Services) server. The goal is to make the API accessible within my organization's network.
Here is what I have completed so far:

Installed Python and added it to the system's PATH.
Created a virtual environment and installed all necessary dependencies (e.g., Flask).
Tested the API locally using python app.py or a similar command, and it is functioning as expected.

What are the steps to host this Python Web API on an IIS server running on Windows OS?

There is a set of details for this at Deploy a Python Flask Application in IIS Server.


If you want virtual environments, then you have to use Linux. 2. Without virtual environments, there are tons of tutorials to set up Flask web apps on IIS like https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/


@OldBoy I followed the steps mentioned in the link, but I'm encountering the error: "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." What could be causing this issue?

It is impossible for anyone to guess what may cause the error. You will need to gather information from the server logs, or do some debugging of  your code.

@OldBoy I checked the log files for errors but didn’t find any issues. Did you try the steps mentioned in the link, and are they working correctly for you? Apart from the steps in the link, did you make any additional configurations?

Sorry, I have not actually tried this yet as my Flask application is not complete.
